# Filter for dc.js data table

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I have created a datatable using dc.js. Now I need to filter it based on a column. Is there any method like `.filter()` to filter the table.

For Example:

`const product_table = dc.dataTable("#product-table");`

Table structure:

```
Product     Name
1           A
2           B
3           C
4           D
5           E
6           A
```

I need to filter only the name column which has value as `A`. Is there any filter like `product_table.filter("A")`?

Comment: Do you want to filter all the charts using this filter, or just the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

product_table.filter(p=>p.Name == "A")

Comment: I don't think this answer is related to dc.js

Answer (score 0):

I create a new graph with name as the dimension (you might display it, as a rowChart or [selectMenu](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/select.html) for instance)

Then you can apply the .filter() to this graph and it will automatically redraw the table

You can skip the graph and directly create a crossfilter dimension and filter it, but I find it easier to keep a graph as a wrapper.